druid unused data source deletion on metadata
i deployed the druid cluster
1- master node
1- query node
3- data nodes
unused datasources not deleting on metadata
my coordinator-overlord/runtime.properties
druid.host=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
druid.service=druid/coordinator
#druid.plaintextPort=xxx

druid.tlsPort=xxx
druid.enablePlaintextPort=false
druid.enableTlsPort=true
druid.coordinator.kill.compaction.on=true
druid.coordinator.startDelay=PT10S
druid.coordinator.period=PT5S
druid.manager.segments.pollDuration=PT5S
druid.coordinator.asOverlord.enabled=true
druid.coordinator.asOverlord.overlordService=druid/overlord
druid.indexer.queue.startDelay=PT5S
druid.indexer.storage.type=metadata
druid.coordinator.kill.compaction.on=True
druid.coordinator.kill.compaction.period=P1D
druid.coordinator.kill.rule.on=True
druid.coordinator.kill.rule.on=True
druid.coordinator.period.metadataStoreManagementPeriod=P1D
druid.coordinator.kill.rule.period=P1D
druid.coordinator.kill.rule.durationToRetain=P1M

====================================
still unused data source not deleting

Please confirm that you have kill tasks running to remove unused data from deep storage. Also check the configuration of your automated metadata cleanup.
https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/data-management/delete
https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/operations/clean-metadata-store
